# virtualbox download and installation error

Tags: apt, system-installation, virtualbox

Im trying to download and install virtualbox 5.0 by
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0`

and get the error:

```
unable to locate package virtualbox-5.0
Couldn't find any package by regex 'virtualbox-5.0'
```

I get the same error messages for 4.3, 5.1 ...

Am I doing something wrong here? how should I install the `5` version?

my second question- I need to download and install guest addition, do I need to download a specific version for 5.0? or other version?

**EDIT:**

1. If I run the command `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` I get 4.1 version.
2. the installation is offline, so I download list of `.deb` files (apt-get install- to file, then download the deb files and after that install it on offline computer), and commands like `update` or `autoremove` or just `apt-get install` doesn't fits on my case.

thanks.

Comment: which ubuntu version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

That is because there is not a package in the standard repositories with such a name, to get the latest in the repositories then run:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

If you already have the `virtualbox` `.deb` file you wish to install it then simply `cd` into the relevant folder and run (`<package-name>` being the name of the `.deb` file you wish to install):

```
sudo dpkg -i <package-name>
```

If you do not already have it then you may download it from the [official page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) (there are download links at the top of the page).

If you want it from the official VirtualBox repository though you will need to run:

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list
```

Then add the key (for version 16.04 and above):

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Or this one (for version below 16.04):

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

Which is currently (at the time of this writing) the latest version, though you may replace the version number with whichever you like the install that version.

[Source and further reference.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

To answer your second question: the guest addition comes with the VirtualBox version you install. You can install it on a VM by going `Devices > Insert Guest Additions Installation CD` (though you will have to do this again every time you upgrade your VirtualBox version as the guest additions installation doesn't upgrade by itself on your VMs). Ubuntu will ask you if you wish to run the contents of the inserted CD, say you do and then it will install it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, please see my edits

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: And I understand that you have now downloaded the relevant `.deb` file (I have updated my answer with installation instructions for that) or could you further clarify what you mean?

Comment: my ubuntu version is 12.04 xubuntu. Im trying to download the 15 version but I get those errors.. if I just type `virtualbox` without any specific version, it downloads the 4.1 version

Comment: @userd: I don't think that that virtualbox version is available for 12.04 in the standard repositories, you should try the official virtualbox one I gave installation instructions for. Or try downloading the 12.04 latest version from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) (at the top of the page you will find download links).

Answer (score 0):

If you have now problems while installing Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.*`, use the following command instead:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.*
```

It may save you a lot of time.